VSE and image (slider effect, slideshow)
This year i want to make a video of all my vacation photo's and movies.
I wonder though if there is some kind of addon that would simplify the workflow of adding an image from transparent (or other video effects) to non transparent then after a second (or adjustable time) repeat it when adding the next image.  (as i have about 1200 pictures).
